# How to properly display all the sub values for JSON records using React.js

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display the following data values from the JSON record for **context, id, productname, price, categories, tags and description** with the code below.

I can only display **context** value and **id** value.

I am not sure how to get the remaining the values for **productname, price, categories, tags and description**.

Below is the script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>

   </head>
   <body>
<script src="build/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script src="build/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Application extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

rec: {"results": 
[

{"context": "context1", "id": "101",
"service": [{"type": "men", "attributes": {"curation": {"rating": 0.0}, 
"main": {"productname": "Men Wear","price": "10 usd"}, 
"additionalInformation": {"categories": ["Men-Wear"], "tags": ["smart guys", "young men"], "description": "For Men only ",
 "createHolder": "admin"}} }]},


{"context": "context2", "id": "102",
"service": [{"type": "women", "attributes": {"curation": {"rating": 0.0}, 
"main": {"productname": "women wear","price": "20 usd"}, 
"additionalInformation": {"categories": ["Women-Wear"], "tags": ["first Ladies", "smart ladies"], "description": "For women Only ",
 "createHolder": "Ann Ball"}} }]}

], "page": 1, "total_pages": 1, "total_results": 2}




    };
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>

         //
          <ul>
            {this.state.rec.results.map((obj, i) => (
              <li key={i}>
                {obj.id} - {obj.context} 
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Helpful tip: Stack Overflow is an amazing resource, and it currently attracts a lot of talented programmers who want to offer help to learners. However, to use it in the best possible way, something of a mindset change is required. There's plenty of sites where one can ask "hey, could someone write code to do X?". On Stack Overflow, that might be seen as a request for free labour, or it may even result in the question being closed as "needs focus" (an official close reason).

Comment: It is much better to adopt an approach of believing you can do things yourself. I recommend asking the question "How can I do X?". Not only does this make it clear to readers that you are happy to do the bulk of the work, but it also emphasises your confidence to yourself, perhaps with the result that you end up resolving issues that you might previously have gotten stuck on. In other words, positive thinking is a great asset for engineers to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you *actually* want.

`results` returns an array. Each entry has a `context` and `id`.

What you're asking for, `productname`, `price`, `categories`, etc. is contained in each result's `service` property, itself an array, so you'd also need to iterate over that, in pseudo-code:

```
results.map(r => {
  const { id, context, service } = r

  // "id" and "context" are available. 
  // "service" needs to be iterated and picked apart.

  service.map(s => {
    const { 
      attributes: { 
        main: { productname, price },
        additionalInformation: { categories, tags, description }
      }
    } = s

    // Now "productname", "price", and "description" are available.
    // "categories" and "tags" are arrays and need to either be
    // iterated if you need them in their own components, or just
    // `join`ed if you need a string.

    const sCats = categories.join(', ') // Etc.
  })
})
```

What you need to actually do with these values depends on your actual requirements.

You would be much, much better off breaking this in to multiple components, e.g., a component to display an individual result, a component to display each `service` entry, and potentially more depending on the complexity of what you need to show (and how), and whether or not there is any interactivity on any of them, e.g., `categories` and `tags` might be some sort of pill input.

Comment: Thank you Sir Dave for your response and getting back to me. please can you show me little integration of your amazing solution with my code above so that I can understand it properly. thank you

Comment: Am getting some token error. I guess am not doing the integration properly. can you help me further. thanks

Comment: @NancyMooree As I stated, this is pseudo-code (although it's pretty close). Basically you need to iterate `service` and pull out the additional data from `attributes`. I mean... this is basic JS object traversal.